# Desktop publishing / page layout for Linux

Tags: linux, text-processing, wysiwyg, desktop-publishing

I'm looking for a page layout, or desktop publishing, software for Linux.  I'm really just looking for anything where I can layout multiples frames of text on a page. It should be style based, so I can change the style of all the frames and all the various parts of the text.

I have tried Scribus and was not happy with it. It is lacking in text formatting abilities, simple things like borders are missing.

I've used OpenOffice Writer in the past, and am happy with it's text formatting, but it's box layout abilities are severely limited. Draw is better for layout, but it loose text style capabilities (each frame can have only one style).

Is there any software for Linux that has good frame layout and text styles?

Answer (score 3):

By looking at this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_desktop_publishing_software), I can see there aren't too many free alternatives for Linux. In fact you've already tried all WYSIWYG DTP software (excepting LyX).

You say you weren't happy with Scribus. Well, it has a lot of options but some are hidden in that interface.

Paragraph borders are not missing in Scribus. Draw a text frame <kbd>T</kbd>, write some text in it and while it is selected press <kbd>F2</kbd>, or right-click and select <kbd>Properties</kbd>. Now go to <kbd>Colors</kbd> tab, click the <kbd>Edit Line color properties</kbd> button and choose a color for the frame border. Now go to <kbd>Line</kbd> tab and choose the desired width.

[image]

The missing feature here is that you can't add borders only to specific sides. But you can draw lines with the Line tool <kbd>L</kbd> and edit their properties with the properties window <kbd>F2</kbd>. When you're done, select the text frame and its borders (the lines you draw) with your mouse and press <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> to group them together.

[image]

Scribus also supports text styles. Select a text frame and press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> to open the Story editor.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but those are the borders I'm looking for. I'm looking for per-paragraph style borders. If I have to draw individual borders, or create frames per paragraph, I'll be subjected to undue amount of work. As you saw, the styles editor doesn't include borders.